# Replace invalid characters when saving excel as PDF

Tags: vba, excel

sorry for the inconvenience. I've tried to google (I always said "google is my friend"), but everything I try only give me an error in VBA.

I would like to add a function, which replace invalid characters (!"#¤%&/()=?`^*>;:@£${[]}|~\,.'¨´+-) in filename with "_".

This is my current (and working) macro:

```
Sub Save_to_PDF()
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim name, datedd As String

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("sheet1")).Select

    datedd = Date
    strFilename = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B2")
    v = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(strFilename & " document " & datedd & " .pdf", "PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf")

    On Error GoTo openfile

    If FileExists(v) Then
        Kill v
    End If

    If VarType(v) = vbString Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Activate
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, filename:=v, _
          Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
          IgnorePrintAreas:=False, From:=1, To:=1, OpenAfterPublish:=True
    End If
    Exit Sub

openfile:
    MsgBox "You have one file open allready whith that name. Please try again", vbInformation, "Please close file"
    Exit Sub
End sub
```

Comment: I'm intrigued that `End Sub` doesn't feature at any point, perhaps that will lead to some issues - could you change the last `Exit` to an `End`?

Comment: Sorry I did not get it all written down. There is an end sub in the macro. I've edited the text:) Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Do you have a list of those invalid characters? If yes, update your question with them. If not, get that list.

Comment: Updated text with invalid characters.

Answer (score 1):

The following Function will replace pre-selected characters with an alternative:

```
Function clean_filename(fname As String, replace_with As String)
    Dim inv_chars As String
    Dim cpos As Long
    invchars = "!""#¤%&/()=?`^*>;:@£${[]}|~\,.'¨´+-"
    For cpos = 1 To Len(invchars)
        fname = Replace(fname, Mid(invchars, cpos, 1), replace_with)
    Next
    clean_filename = fname
End Function
```

You could use this by adding `v = clean_filename(v,"_")` once you've captured v (as a string).

However, you've included `.` and `/` in your invalid character list, and both are important to filenames so you may want to consider removing them and/or dealing with those in a different way.